# Beamer doesn't honor handout-specific color theme properly when different color themes are set for presentation and handout mode

Tags: beamer, themes

I'd like to produce colored lecture slides for an actual presentation, and a black-and-white version as a handout.

I have specified different color themes for presentation and handout mode, respectively. I suppose this should work in principle; for instance, the `beamer` documentation gives an example of a mode-specific theme on page 207:

> \mode<'presentation>{\usetheme{Berlin}}

Then again, the documentation also states, in section "21.3 Details on Modes",

> The ⟨*text*⟩ should not do anything fancy that involves mode switches or including other files

(p. 210), so I'm not sure that I'm handling the use of color schemes the right way.

Here's a MWE of what I do:

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\mode<presentation>{\usecolortheme{spruce}}
\mode<handout>{\usecolortheme{seagull}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{It Ain't Easy Being Green}
Green, or not too green, that is the question.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

When I leave out the `handout` option in the `documentclass` statement, the output is as desired:

[image]

However, when I compile with the `handout` option included, there's still a green frame title bar:

[image]

When I comment out the line `\mode<presentation>{\usecolortheme{spruce}}`, the output is as desired in `handout` mode:

[image]

Am I asking too much from the `mode` feature, or is this a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `presentation` mode includes the modes `beamer`, `trans` and `handout`, see this diagram from the beamer user guide:

[image]

So if you don't want the colour theme in `handout`, use the `beamer` mode.

```
\documentclass[handout]{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\mode<beamer>{\usecolortheme{spruce}}
\mode<handout>{\usecolortheme{seagull}}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\frametitle{It Ain't Easy Being Green}
Green, or not too green, that is the question.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I guess I should've kept on reading page 210...

Comment: @Turtle It is also on page 88 :)